# "Add Expires Headers" - what about HTML?

Tags: http-headers

Probably quite a basic question but I want to be 100% sure...

It's recommended to place "Add Expire Header" rules in your htaccess file, but my question is that, the HTML ***text*** within my site changes very often, i.e. written content - so, just to be clear, adding the below is completely fine given that my content (text) changes regularly?

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

I want repeat visitors to see my fresh content of course, hence why I'm asking

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not completely fine given your requirement:

> I want repeat visitors to see my fresh content

If you serve an HTML page with headers that indicate that the client can cache that response until (now + two days), then if the user refreshes that page, for the next two days the browser will return the cached HTML.

Comment: hmmm, so it seems that this type of caching is really for a site that doesn't change too often then?